# Change Indesign Reference version in Excel VBA reference list

Tags: excel, adobe-indesign, vba

I have a tool to create a document in Adobe Indesgin through Excel VBA macro and used Adobe Indesign CC type Library(Version 9.0). Now, I have updated Adobe Indesign software and in excel macro ver 9.0 library is missing and ver 11.0 is available to use. 
If select ver 11.0 and execute the code it throws me an error (Can't find project or library) at this line.

Public DocReport As Indesign.Document

Comment: You'll have to redefine the new object name. Just delete `Indesign.Document` and then start typing or using intellisense to see what objects starting with "In" or "InDesign show up. You can also use object browser to see what library and objects are now called

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck Adobe Indesign 9.0 in the `References - VBAProject` dialog and then check Adobe Indesign 11.0.

Often developers will set use Early Binding (set a reference to a specific library) during the development process. BUt at the time of release they will switch to Late Binding.

When using Late Binding you will declare all Objects from an external library as Objects and then use CreateObject to set the references to the lastest version of the library that is on the current machine. In this way, it will not matter which version of a library the system is running as long as that version support the required functionality.

```
Public DocReport As Object

Set DocReport = CreateObject("Indesign.Document")
```